# How to replace a part of a string with something that depends on the bit replaced?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string that contains tokens for images:

```
"Hello World bla [image-37388] bla bla"
```

Now how can I replace that token with the url of that image? Of course the url depends on the number in the token. How can I fire up the regex to find it, but then feed the value of the replaced part to a function that then returns the correct replacement string?

I'm new to javascript so I'm glad for any help.

Comment: What would be the expected output, please provide a better example.

Comment: Here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you, I must have overlooked that. Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [**capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to retain the part that you want matched and then access the back-reference `$1` to insert the value back inside of the string in the replacement call.

```
var s = 'Hello World bla [image-37388] bla bla'
var r = s.replace(/\[image-(\d+)]/, 'http://liberty.edu/$1.gif');
console.log(r) //=> 'Hello World bla http://liberty.edu/37388.gif bla bla'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to get the value, do your stuff, then replace

```
var someString = "Hello World bla [image-37388] bla bla";

// this sets newSubString to ["[image-37388]"]
var newSubString = someString.match(/[\[][a-z-0-9]*[\]]/);

// do something with the substring
var someUrl = "some url";
//replace it with your new url

someString = someString.replace(newSubString[0], someUrl);

console.log(someString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that accepts 3 parameters. The String with the pattern to match, the baseURL where your images are kept and a file type of the image.

```
var string = "Hello World bla [image-37388] bla bla";
var baseURL = "www.whatever.com/images/"
var fileType = "jpg"


function getURL(urlString, baseURL, fileType) {
    var matches = urlString.match(/\[image-(\d+)?\]/);
    if (matches[1]) {
        return baseURL + matches[1] + "." + fileType;     
    }        
}

getURL(string, baseURL, fileType);
```

Use the String object's built-in `match` function to find the token in question and parse, returning the formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) with a capture group and a replacer function:

```
var input = "Hello World bla [image-37388] bla bla"
var regex = /\[image-(\d+)]/;
var result = input.replace(regex, function(match,$1){
   return '<img src="path\\to\\myimg-' + $1 + '.jpg">';
});
alert(result);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lxwfj6s/